# jQuery sum of total time in input fields

Tags: jquery, input, time, sum

I'm needing jQuery to automatically give me the sum of the time in the input fields. I would like it to show the total in another input field with the value set to the total time. Example below.

```
input 1: 18:30   //format mm:ss
input 2:  3:00 
input 3:  0:00
input 4:  0:30
------------------
Total:   22:00
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this might help u mate :) Before u copy paste the code try to understand what happens behind the scenes.

**HTML**

```
<input value="1:45" size="5">Time 1
<input value="1:30" size="5">Time 2
<input value="1:32" size="5">Time 3
<input value="5:30" size="5">Time 4
<button id="addTimes">Add times</button>
<br>Result<span id="timeSum"></span>
```

**Script**

```
  Number.prototype.padDigit = function () {
        return (this < 10) ? '0' + this : this;
    }

 $("#addTimes").on('click', function () {
      var t1 = "00:00";
      var mins = 0;
      var hrs = 0;
        $('input').each(function () {
            t1 = t1.split(':');
            var t2 = $(this).val().split(':');
            mins = Number(t1[1]) + Number(t2[1]);
            minhrs = Math.floor(parseInt(mins / 60));
            hrs = Number(t1[0]) + Number(t2[0]) + minhrs;
            mins = mins % 60;
            t1 = hrs.padDigit() + ':' + mins.padDigit()

        });
        $('#timeSum').text(t1);
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ov9hL8k/)

**FYI**

[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[ParseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

The below code is a round about way of achieving the same. However, if you do want to go for a better approach, I would suggest you to use Moments.js, which comes in with various features for handling datetime in javascropt/jquery

```
var score = $('.input').val();
var minutes  = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var tmpSec = 0;
$(score).each(function(index){
    var minSec = this;
    var timeParts = minSec.split(":");
    minutes = minutes + parseInt(timeParts[0]);
    seconds = seconds + parseInt(timeParts[1]);
});
if (seconds > 60){
    tmpSec = Math.round(seconds / 60);
    seconds = seconds % 60;
}

tmpMins = minutes + parseInt(tmpSec);
finalOutput = tmpMins + ":" + seconds;
```

For simplicity I have assumed all your input boxes, apart from the result box has a class "input". You can modify that accordingly.